# Flutter Firebase Function/Messaging not being triggered when document is added

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this function that should be listening to when a document is created in the Activity subcollection under Users, however it seems like the function is not being triggered when a document is being made.

```
exports.sendActivityNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('Users/{userId}/Activity/{activityId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Activity notification triggered")

    // Extract the user ID and activity data
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const activity = snapshot.data();

    console.log('Activity:', activity);

    // Retrieve the 'postedBy' field from the activity document
    const postedBy = activity.userId;

    console.log('User ID:', postedBy);

    // Lookup the FCM token from the Users collection
    try {
      const userDoc = await admin.firestore().doc(`Users/${postedBy}`).get();
      const user = userDoc.data();

      console.log('User:', user);

      var body;
      // if activity type is a like or comment
      if (activity.type === 'like') {
        body = `${user.username} reacted to your post!`;
      } else {
        body = `${user.username} commented on your post!`;
      }

      if (user && user.fcmToken) {
        // Construct the notification message
        const message = {
          notification: {
            title: 'New Activity',
            body: body
          },
          token: user.fcmToken,
        };

        console.log(message)

        // Send the notification
        return admin.messaging().send(message);
      } else {
        console.log('No FCM token found for user:', postedBy);
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user document:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  });
```

This is my database scheme

collection: Users
subcollection of Users: Activity

I then tried to create a different collection called Tests and did this:

```
exports.send = functions.firestore
  .document('Test/{userId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Activity notification triggered")
  });
```

Seemed to work everytime a document is created.

I feel like the issue has to do with the Users/{userId}/Activity/{activityId} part of it and there are no answers past 2021 in stackoverflow

Edit:

Here is the flutter code that writes to the database

```
class ActivityActions {
  final _userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  final _postsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Posts');

  Future<void> reactToPostActivity(String postId, String userId,
      String userPhotoUrl, String username, String postPhotoUrl) async {
    // create Timestamp of now as Timestamp
    final Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());

    final post = LikesNotificationModel(
        id: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        userId: userId,
        postId: postId,
        userPhotoUrl: userPhotoUrl,
        username: username,
        postPhotoUrl: postPhotoUrl,
        timestamp: timestamp);

    await _userCollection
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("Activity")
        .doc(postId)
        .set(post.toMap());

    print("Created post activity");
  }
```

In addition, here are my most recent ids (newest is last)
'0kBWYwEI0mpjAqpAzoQH', 'At8GvxC0gVky1SGKzPU0'
and thenb after i called that reactToPostActivity(), I get
'0kBWYwEI0mpjAqpAzoQH', 'At8GvxC0gVky1SGKzPU0', 'HjPiB4Gqg2wulpLsxulR'

so i can see it is added. I also can see the function being triggered when I create a document myself in the database, but not in flutter applicaiton

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between using the console or client code when it comes to triggering functions.  Are you saying that the client code actually creates the document with no errors, but the function doesn't get triggered?